# show or hide button using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two button start and stop. on page load stop button hide and start button show.
when i click start button this button hide and stop button show.

i am using `.hide()` method.

Jquery Code:

```
$(window).load(function ()
{
$('#stop').hide();
});
```

It's working but issue is when page load this (stop button) will show for a second(like a blink) and then hide. i want to hide completely mean i don't want to show stop button when page load.

Comment: use `document.ready` it fill fire couple `ms` before `window.load` or hide it with css first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have used the [load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) handler, So till all the resources of the page is loaded the script is not executed.

One possible solution is to use a css rule, with the id selector to hide the element like

```
#stop{display: none;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hide it once only the button has loaded, not the whole window.

```
$("#stop").load(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Otherwise you can always use CSS to hide it with `display:none;`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use CSS :

```
#stop { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnStop").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide();
        $("#btnPlay").show();
    })
    $("#btnPlay").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).hide();
        $("#btnStop").show();
    })
})
```